# Xdebug with PhpStorm, why the session time so short?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

When I start listening for PHP debug connections on PhpStorm, open my web site on browser, I can look the debug info, but it's so short that I can't get more useful info.

So, how can I do?

```
PhpStorm version: 2016.1.3
PHP: 7.0.13 
Xdebug : 2.4.1
```

Comment: check your web-server setting with `timeout` settings

Comment: niginx: fastcgi_connect_timeout  300;
         fastcgi_send_timeout  300;
          fastcgi_read_timeout  300;

Comment: It's pure web server (nginx in your case)/FastCGI config issue -- @AlexandrKapustin is right here. Cannot say what particular setting it is though .. but I was dealing with this myself on IIS where increased timeouts do the job.